# Two encrypted Windows installs?

Tags: disk-encryption, boot

The idea is to share a computer with another user. Rather than having separate accounts, I'd like to have two separate windows installs. I'm familiar with full disk encryption. I've used True Crypt and Diskcryptor. Ideally I'd like there to be two encrypted windows installs. And how easy would it be if the bootloader just selected which one to boot by which password was entered?

That might be too much to ask, so booting of a flash drive to boot into the second Windows OS is what I'm thinking.

Has anyone done this before? How do I do this?

Comment: Hmm. Edit the LUKS code to allow this. Might work, but painful. Interested to see other ideas.

Comment: That is not a question for this stack. It is MUCH better suited for superuser. However, I suggest you check out windows-to-go